# Oracle Trigger inserting row into custom table

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have a Post-Insert Oracle trigger that is simply going to be used to insert a row into a table when the triggered table has a record added to it. My code is a simple insert:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO R5CHECKLISTMAP(CLM_CHKLINECODE, CLM_SYSTEMCODE)
VALUES(10, 'TEST');

END;
```

However, I get the error:

**ORA 01006 - Bind Variable does not exist POST-INSERT 10 Before Binding**

I know this has to be something simple, but I cannot figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: Could you please post your trigger statement? There should be something with : or &

Comment: Are you talking about an `after insert for each row` trigger in the database?  Or are you talking about a trigger in Oracle Forms?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, when a row is added to the table "R5TASKCHECKLISTS", I want the trigger to insert a row into the table "R5CHECKLISTMAP".

Comment: Your error message does not match the code you posted. Please post the *real* (and *complete*) trigger code.

Comment: I am working from within an application front end in which I select the table to place a trigger on, select Post-Insert or Post-Update, and write the SQL statement from there. I assume the other pieces of the code are written in the back end based on the selections I make on the interface. This is the only code I have in "my" SQL statement.

Comment: There should still be a compiled trigger somewhere in your schema. So, someone must have access to the generated code.

Comment: Please at least confirm that you're talking about an Oracle Forms application?